# Excel Data Import By row

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am using Excel to manage lab sample flow.

If at some point in the workflow, the sample does not pass onto the next step in the protocol, it will be eliminated from the next sheet I create.

I determine which samples pass by my using excel to calculate concentrations, etc.- those that fail output 'FAIL' in the excel sheet.

So I would like excel to import the entire row data (or certain headers) automatically into a new sheet for samples that pass. Is it possible?

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Import all data to excel.
Calculate whatever you want. If PASS, copy the data to another sheet.

```
CEL A2
=IF(A1>9;"TRUE";"FALSE")
ANother cel

=IF(A2="TRUE";A1;0)
```